# How to coordinate and parallelize between multiple ant tasks and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have this scenario:

I have a Jenkins Job which basically performs the build and followed to that it starts deploying the artifacts into the virtual machines.

Here is my problem. At the moment I deploy artifacts one by one sequentially i.e. via ant task from the same `build.xml` file.

```
Deploy and install Artifact 1
Deploy and install Artifact 2
Deploy and install Artifact 3
Deploy and install Artifact 4
```

Each of these deployments take 30 mins.

So I am interested to know how I can plan to parallelize this.

As the deployment is not that resource intensive I am not interested to use Jenkins agents. So it will probably be a bit overkill.

Comment: you have one jenkins job that calls four ant targets? or four jenkins jobs that each call an ant target?

Comment: I have one Jenkins job that calls four ant targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want four executors on your jenkins controller. You can do this by going to manage jenkins > Manage Nodes > Master > Configure, and change the "# of executors" to 4

Then you'll want to split your jenkins job into four jobs - each calling one of your ant targets.  The [build flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) is genius, however you may not need it.

Comment: Do I really have to go to master slave way, as I was thinking that may be a overkill for achieving this.

Comment: You don't need to add slaves, I edited the answer to be clearer.  Each node (master and/or slaves) can have 1 or more executors - think of them as execution threads.  One job can run on each executor, they can be concurrent.